# Is Calux still part of the game of Truth or Dare?

Tags: plot-explanation, truth-or-dare

In the climax of the movie *[Truth or Dare (2018)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_or_Dare_(2018_film)))*, the demon possessing the game is brought into the game, and asked a truth, answering by possessing a current player. After answering, Calux apparently disappears and isn't seen again.

At the end of the movie, is the demon Calux still part of the game, and if so, can it be killed by not taking part, just the same as the humans?

Answer (score 1):

Once someone is part of the game, they stay part of it till they die. It's the same for Calux. At the end they create a video which goes viral and people all over the world become part of it. It's going to be Calux's turn after a ton of people die. And when it does become Calux's turn, he's sneaky enough to manipulate the opponent to get is way through.